# Add class if another element has active class and delete this if not with javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, svg

I'm trying to add a class to a div if another element in the page has an active class.
I would like to add "reveal" class to a specific div if one svg element has the active class.
It works manually with HTML but I can't trigger my "reveal" class in a dynamic way if I change the active class in another element. I succeeded to change the active class, but there is no effect on my div element ...

Here is my HTML :

```
<svg>
   <g class="region dep28"> <!-- I can for exemple, manually put "active" class here and it 
    triggers the "reveal" class lower -->
    <path class="st0"/>
   </g>
   <g class="region dep45">
    <path class="st1"/>
   </g>
</svg>
<div class="clublist club28"> <!-- Has "reveal" if I put manually "active" class upper --> ..... </div>
<div class="clublist club45">
 .....
</div>`
```

Here is my JavaScript :

```
$(".region").click(function () {
  $(".region").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");   
});


if ( $(".dep28").hasClass('active') ) {

    $(".club28").addClass("reveal");   
} else {  $(".club28").removeClass("reveal");
}
```

So I would like to add the "reveal" class on .club45 if I have the active class on .dep45 ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you move the if-else statement into your click function, since the reveal doesn't get triggered as it's not in the same function.

```
$(".region").click(function () {

  $(".region").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");   

  //Retrieve class names
  var classNames = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/)

  //Get the dep+id
  var depClass = classNames[1]; //dep28

  //Retrieve the id
  var id = depClass.split('dep')[1];

  //This if-else statement has been moved inside the click function
  if ($(".dep" + id).hasClass('active')) {
    $(".club" + id).addClass("reveal");   
  } 
  else {  
    $(".club" + id).removeClass("reveal");
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works !
Last question : I have 6 cases of "if conditions" (.club28, .club45,...) what is the cleanest way  to write this in JS ?

Comment: Glad I could help! I have updated the answer, which will make it dynamic instead of static. However, if you want a static way, a switch case might be sufficient.

Comment: Here, the "reveal" class is not removed if another dep is active. I'm sorry I'm not comfortable with JavaScript...

Comment: I think you can fetch all deps and remove the active class before adding the active class to the region.